# How do I resize an image into a perfect square using sharp in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sharp

I'm creating the server for an ecommerce web app, and I cannot seem to resize the images into a perfect square. Is it that I need a set width and height to make it a perfect square?

Answer (score 2):

According to the sharp API documentation, the resize method can accept an optional "fit" parameter that would be useful.

See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize

That would give something like :

```
sharp(input)
.resize({width:512, height:512, fit:"cover"})
.toBuffer()
.then(data => {
    // ... do something with data
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you make the `width` and `height` properties the same value you can make a resized square image. The `fit` property takes care of how the resized image `fits` in that square if your original `width` and `height` are different and not of the same size.

Comment: Not to be rude but how does this answer the question?

Comment: Ok Ok, just formulated an answer :-)